# Setting up Dependency Injection using Unity to pass instance of class into a constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection

I am sure there are answers on here to my question, though I just don't either quite understand what I'm looking for or what I'm reading... Also, not 100% sure DI is what I should be using in this case.

I am attempting to use Unity for my DI. I am injecting dependency into ASP.Net Web API Controllers. And so far so good.

I am injecting Services into my controllers that the controller will require. For example, in one of my controllers I have:

```
private TransactionService _transactionService;

public TransactionsController(TransactionService transactionService)
{
    _transactionService = transactionService;
}
```

In this case I am injecting an instance of TransactionService into the controller. This is all working.

My WebApiConfig.cs contains the following, which as i understand it actually performs the injection:

```
   var container = new UnityContainer();
   container.RegisterType<ServiceBase>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
   config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);
```

I can show you my `UnityResolver` if needed.

Now the part I'm struggling with...

My services all inherit from an Abstract class `ServiceBase` - in its simplest for it looks like this:

```
public abstract class ServiceBase : IDisposable
{

    internal Account _account;

    public ServiceBase(){}
}
```

What I would like to do is create the `Account` during my injection process and pass it in somehow so that my injected services don't need to deal with instansiating the account.

The moment I try adding any constructors to my services to accept an Account I receive the message to ensure my controllers have a parameterless constructor.

So.. how do i set up my DI so that I can inject services into my controllers and also inject a pre-instantiated instance of Account into my services?

**Update**

I forgot to mention (sorry Wiktor) - I would like to NOT use Attributes if possible. It seems strange in my mind that we can use DI to unhook dependency and then go and put a bunch of dependent attributes everywhere. I quite possibly just don't understand the DI concept correctly, though this doesn't seem right to me

Comment: Use interfaces when you use DI because it will be very easy while unit testing. In my projects I mostly prefer interfaces and so that there it will not be tightly coupled. Also while doing DI just see the concept of loosely coupled and keep unit testing in mind.

Comment: Can you just explain clearly what are you trying with account property while DI ?

Comment: It's a little difficult explaining what I am trying as I have little idea what i am supposed to try - hence asking here. I have explained what I am trying to achieve, which is I want to instantiate my account object and have that injected into any other class that needs it - and not have Unity instantiate the account object for me.

Comment: Also - how do I code my unity config against the interface as they aren't allowed constructors? Perhaps you could post an answer as to how you do this?

Comment: Agree with your update about attributes.

Answer (score 0):

That should be simple, just make the additional property public and add the dependency attribute on it.

```
 [Dependency]  
 public Account _account { get; set; }
```

Unity should be able to inject the attribute and you can even register the `Account` class in an ordinary way (for example with an injection factory).

Comment: Would it be better to use a public property (as you stated in your answer) rather than a public field (as you have shown in your code)?

Comment: Ah - sorry, I should have put in my question - I am trying to do this without attributes - is this possible? To me by putting that on the class my class now has a dependency on DI (of sorts) - kinda goes against the whole idea in my mind. Also - what do you do if you don't have access to the 'Account' code?

Comment: Also, is this not leaving Unity to create my Account object, thus creating an instance for every `[Dependency]` it sees? I would like to tell Unity to use a specific instance of `Account` - this will mean I only have to create it the once as opposed to every instance that requires it - if this makes sense.

Comment: @Darren: if you first register a specific instance, it will be always injected. Or you can even have an injection factory, as I said. The factory would return just anything, it could be the same instance always.

Comment: @WiktorZychla - thanks, that's what I thought. Just can't get it to work - stumped as to what to actually code next :)

Comment: I think you should redesign the approach. Have a parameter in the base constructor and add the same parameter in the derived class constructor and call the base constructor from the derived with `base`. No attributes and Unity will resolve it there.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would give some idea for you.

Create an interface for service base and declare Acccount as public property.

Interface for your service:

```
you can also inherit other interfaces.
public interface ITransactionService : IDisposable
{
  IAccount Account{get;set;}
}
```

Implement it in your class:

```
public class TransactionService : ITransactionService{
 private IAccount _account;
 public IAccount Account
 {
   get
     {if(_account==null)_account=new Account(); return _account;}
   set
     {_account=value;}
 }
}
```

Now use the constructor at API controller as shown below:

```
private ITransactionService _transactionService;

public TransactionsController(ITransactionService transactionService)
{
    _transactionService = transactionService;
}
```

Unity resolver:

```
var container = new UnityContainer();
   container.RegisterType<ITransactionService,TransactionService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
   config.DependencyResolver = new UnityResolver(container);
```

So using in this way where property injection and constructor injection used for reducing tightly coupled dependency.

It will be very easy for mocking the interface for unit testing.

You may also create an interface for Account class, so that it could be easy for mocking based on your use.

Comment: I may be missing something here, but how would the `IAccount` instance be injected? It seems your code sample will always create an `Account` instance - what if they wanted a different instance of `IAccount`?

Comment: @DanielKelley That's exactly what I thought when I read this answer. I still have little idea.... My other issue is that I don't know the ID for the account I need to new-up until runtime, so settings in the webapiconfig would be pointless would they not?

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to use attributes, which I totally agree with, the best approach is to have ServiceBase accept the account parameter, like:

```
public abstract class ServiceBase {
  private Account _account;

  public ServiceBase(Account account) {
    this._account = account;
  }
}
```

You will have to declare the same constructor on your derived service as well `TransactionService`. When the controller is instantiated, Unity will correctly create the instance of `Account` class first and then pass it on to your `TransactionService` object via constructor injection. And you should register `Account` object using a life time manager to scope it to singleton.

Hope this helps.